# It's posible to use Federated table in MySQL NDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-cluster

I'm developing a application that needs two diferent databases, this is because one of this databases is per client and the other one is a generic database.

I'm thinking in make a MySQL NDB Cluster and i need to know if it's possible to uses some Federated tables in the Cluster or all must use ndbcluster engine.

If this is not posible, how can i make joins with tables that are in other host using ndbcluster?

Please forget about, why i need this schema (one databse per client and one generic database) because i spent a lot of time thinking which should be the best schema for my application i choosed this one.

Thanks in for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Cluster uses a full version of mysqld (slightly modified), which includes all storage engines included on a standalone version. So the question for your answer is YES, you can have some tables in FEDERATED storage engine, or any other storage engine.

However, only tables with storage engine=ndbcluster will be replicated to all the api nodes connected to the cluster.

The federated approach with a cluster of two api nodes could work, but keep in mind that only those tables with the same storage engine can have referential integrity (FK) between them.

Which version of MySQL Cluster are you using? It is recommended using always the latest GA release (now 7.4.12)

Regards